# Why my module.exports doesn't work?

Tags: node.js

Here is my basic node.js app with only two files:

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
var app = express();

module.exports = { 
  test: "test"
};


// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    // defining  middlewares

app.get('/', routes.index);




http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and my index.js:

```
var server = require('../app');
exports.index = function(req, res){
    console.log(server);
    res.send('Hello world');
};
```

My problem is when I go to `http:\\localhost:3000` , I see in my console `{}` instead of `{test: "test"}` , it looks like the  `module.eports` doesn't work correctly. Why ?

Comment: are u sure it should be ../app ?

Comment: Yes I think, because the index.js is in the folder "routes"

Comment: See [this page](http://www.selfcontained.us/2012/05/08/node-js-circular-dependencies/) regarding circular dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requiring `index.js` from within `app.js`, and then requiring `app.js` from within `index.js`, looks like code smell to me. Additionally, if you use `var app = module.exports = express()` then Express is able to treat your app as middleware (so for instance, you could have a second app that `requires` the first app, and passes some requests to it.

When I need to access `app` inside another required file I do the following:

```
// ./routes/index.js
module.exports = function(app){
  var routes = {};
  routes.index = function(req, res){
    console.log(app.myConfig);
    res.send('Hello world');
  };
  return routes;
};

// ./app.js
var app = module.exports = express();
app.myConfig = {foo:'bar'};
var routes = require('./routes/index.js')(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include app in index.js

indes.js should just be

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    console.log(server);
    res.send('Hello world');
};
```

And I am assuming index.js is in the routes folder like so

```
app.js
routes
  index.js
```

Comment: If I don't include app, then the server is not defined

Comment: Well you can move that to `server.js` and then `require('../server')`. But what are you trying to do with it? As said before it would otherwise be a circular reference and thats not the best way to do things.